# Is redis statitic value instantaneous_output_kbps in Bytes or Bits

Tags: redis

When using the redis-cli INFO command you get an ouput for
*instantaneous_output_kbps* and *instantaneous_input_kbps*, are those statistics measured in **bytes or bits**?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it's measured in bytes, even though it is not documented on the redis website.

This is how redis tracks those internally (see server.c, line 954):

```
    trackInstantaneousMetric(STATS_METRIC_NET_INPUT,
            server.stat_net_input_bytes);
    trackInstantaneousMetric(STATS_METRIC_NET_OUTPUT,
            server.stat_net_output_bytes);
```

this is tracked in bytes, and the `trackInstantaneousMetric` doesn't manipulate the data in any way. It's basically a moving average on the network IO that's measured in bytes.

Comment: and why do you think that it is in bytes?

Comment: 1. Nothing is measured in bits in redis. 2. I know the code. I'll add the reference from the code in my answer.